# Rearrange twelve checkers in six lines of four

Tags: mathematics, board-games

Once there where two men playing checkers. at one time during the game. one of them stopped and said "Look at that, we just arranged twelve checkers in six straight lines of four". Then they finished their checkers game without any more interruptions.

Now assuming that the man was telling the truth, and they were playing the game correctly. how is this possible?

P.S. this problem is also possible with thirty checkers and six lines of seven.
(in the exact same scenario). And don't worry this will fit on the board.

Comment: Pretty sure I've seen this question before

Comment: There are some variations of this puzzle, but this one has a twist.

Comment: Are we going by the title (ten and five) or the body of the question (twelve and six)?

Comment: Oop's I,ll fix that

Comment: Although this puzzle sounds very interesting, it requires knowledge of Checker. Therefore I believe this puzzle needs to be moved to a different Stackexchange community. P.s. I also received a similar feedback from a few on my own puzzle which required some basic geography knowledge.

Comment: Perhaps this would be remedied by tagging it [trivia] or something?  I don't know very much about this kind of thing, though...

Comment: @VHS: No, that's not true. This is a puzzle that requires knowledge of something else, but is not only "identify this thing". Your puzzle was not a puzzle - it was just an exercise in Googling things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason they could do this is because

> they were playing the game called Chinese Checkers, which is played on this board:[image]
>  They simply made a "Star of David" shape (six marbles in a hexagon, then six more marbles each touching exactly two of the inner marbles).

Comment: great job, exactly the right answer. but you can do it on a normal checkers board.